# Can I facebook login on server side?

Tags: facebook, session, authentication

I want to use the facebook 'feed' API on server side.

I expected flow is below.

`1. Log in to Facebook on the server side with my Facebook account. 
 
2. Write some text to the Facebook page with a session on server side.`

I think that it will work if I can login on the server side.

How can I login to faceobook on server side without OAuth?

Comment: What language are you using on your server, and do you want to log in with a real browser or through a socket?

Comment: I'm using node.js with expressjs. and I want to log in with through a socket.

Comment: Login in through a socket? What should this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Page Access Token beforehand (for example via Graph Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), and then use the following endpoint:

```
/{page-id}/feed
```

as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish

Comment: Thanks. But It is different with that I want to know. I want to know log in to facebook on server side that made of expressjs.

Comment: Well, if you're the only user that needs to do that, I don't really see the neccessity to implement a login functionality. Once you have the Access Token you can use it as "Login credentials". Otherwise you need to implement the OAuth Login flow as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in Python:

```
import urllib2,cookielib

def login(username,password):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
    url1 = "https://login.facebook.com"
    url2 = "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1"
    data = "&email="+username+"&pass="+password
    socket = opener.open(url1)
    socket = opener.open(url2,data)
    return socket

socket = login("not_gonna_tell_you@gmail.com","my_password")

if "logout" in socket.read():
    print "OK"
else:
    print "Error"

# or use 'socket' in order to do whatever you wanna do at this point...
```